# NUXT build vs generate and sitemap

Tags: build, nuxt.js, sitemap, generate

My case:
I want to have dynamic routes (ex: page/1). I want to have accessible web also without JS because of SEO and crawlers. So I load data with asyncData. It is ok.

I have nodejs hosting. Nowadays I used deploy in way **yarn build** and **yarn start**.

But I also want to use @nuxtjs/sitemap. But it is generated just with **yarn generate** (minimally in my case).

Probably I miss some point, can you direct me to right way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Server mode (`yarn dev` or `yarn build && yarn start`), the `sitemap.xml` file will be dynamically generate live by the server on each call to your `http://example.com/sitemap.xml` URL.

in Static mode (`yarn generate`), the `sitemap.xml` file will be statically generate once on nuxt generate process in your `dist` directory.